# ASP.Net Menu Rollover Image

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on a project for school in ASP.Net, one of the requirements is that I have to use the menu control. Another requirement is we have to use one of the asp.net controls in a unique way. So I was thinking of something along the lines of a WP tile system, with rollover images. No child or submenu items, you hover over the image, and another image replaces it. Is this even possible, as all I am seeing for images related to menu control is separators, pop-out images, and indicator icons.  [image]

This is what I am thinking of, so when you hover over any item, a new image replaces it.(I know the colors are hideous, they will be changed). If I can't, is it possible to create the menu like above and use CSS to simulate the rollover?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [**site**](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) for the live tile animations using jQuery.

Using this you can easily accomplish your requirement.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is my ultimate goal, but unfortunately this is an ASP.net class, that requires me to use the ASP.net menu control.